# relay control with network and sms with main controller

Tags: microcontroller, c, power-electronics, wireless, electromagnetism

I need this project for a melting plant.
There must be two relays in the control (connected to the device), so if one of them is in trouble, another will work to disconnect.
In the (current check) section, what part is there to make sure the relay is disconnected?
And in the temperature gauge, you have to set a thermometer to stop the relay in the event of an error.
In the (ether) section there should be a network module that connects to the micro and web server through the (main controller).
Please help me make this device.

### Thanks to me (if you can submit a site or article too)[image]

Comment: Relays don't connect/disconnect. Relays are switches so they're open/closed. *so if one of them is in trouble* That's vague, take a step back and describe what situation you want to prevent. Designing for (un)reliability of a component (relay) is not relevant yet at this (system design) stage. So describe how you want the system to behave, detect faults, how it should respond.

Comment: *relays in the control (connected to the device..)* What is "device"? Sure I know it's probably the heating element, so why not write that down (be explicit). Current check is probably something to measure the current used by the heating element. If that is fed by AC then a current transformer based sensor is all you need, these clip around the wire, no need for a sense resistor.

Comment: Desired device
Yes, you guessed it is a thermal device
In fact, there is a metal smelting furnace that should be shut off remotely with confidence and safety... @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: Oh, so sometimes it is unattended (no person present) then I would make sure there's some form of overheating protection (temperature fuse) present that does not rely on software and relays. Maybe the melter has it already build-in.

Comment: Can you help me in this project? @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: No, a few tips and pointers can be given but that's it. Normally you would do such a project with a couple of students for learning and education. If you "just want the device" then buy some ready made module.

Comment: @vahidsamis - Welcome to EE.SE :-) However, your question "*Please help me make this device*" is "too broad" to be a good fit for this site. Please read the [tour] and [help] to learn more about this site. The Stack Exchange sites are not typical forums; they are specifically Q&A sites. You need to ask a clear single question, with limited bounds / scope, which can be answered in a reasonable amount of time. Unbounded questions like "help with this project", where there isn't one best answer, don't fit here. When you have a *specific* clear question, you can ask that type of question here :-)

Answer (score 1):

Industrial control systems of a safety/mission-critical nature are designed with the concept of "redundancy", which is probably what you refer to. In such safety systems, you have two 2 pole safety relays with forcibly guided contacts. One pole controls the application, the other pole is used to supervise the state of the relay. If it gets stuck, then you'll be able to tell.

On the highest integrity levels, such as ISO 13849-1 PL d or PL e, each relay is typically supervised by 2 microcontrollers, that checks that the relay is indeed in the expected position. That may or may not be overkill here, depending on how critical the application is. In my experience, everything in melting plants is critical - if not in terms of safety, then in terms of cost at production standstill.

All of this, PCB and software both, needs to be designed by professionals. So if you have no clue what any of the above means, you must consult someone who does.

I wouldn't recommend using hobbyist junk such as Raspberry Pi for professional use in general, but not inside a melting plant in particular. You'll have massive transients, voltage surges and magnetic fields. The hobbyist board is likely to run amok in such an environment, since it was not built to handle that. I'm guessing this is for some "IoT" where you intend to access the device over internet? It can perhaps work if you place the board outside the plant...

There are plenty of companies that specialize in various controllers for industrial use, so why not buy a pre-made system rather than re-inventing the wheel?